# console giving Output in other text format

Tags: c++

I am doing my work but suddenly while reading data from file, i suddenly faced text in other form i also carried a small test to check whether is it my code fault or Visual Studio 2012 gone mad. I also debug but values in "line[]" coming correct. But i found small test is still giving me same thing:
here is my small code test:

```
file: input.txt
{
value := (rate * dollar) + (rate1 * dollar1);
totalvalue := value / 2;
t1 = ivariable > 10 && ivariable < 100
    {
        value := (rate * dollar) + (rate1 * dollar1);
        totalvalue := value / 2;
    }
}
```

code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void main(){
    const int si = 1500;
        string line[si];
        ifstream infile;
        infile.open("input.txt");

        cout<<"Reading"<<endl;
    //  infile>>data;
    //  cout<<data<<endl;
        int a=0;
        int size=0;
    //  string line[1500];
    //  for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        while(!infile.eof()){

            getline(infile,line[a],'\n');
            cout<<line[a]<<endl;
            a++;
        }
}
```

and the output:
[image]

Any idea please share......

Comment: i dont know why "`a" are coming with my original texts

Comment: `main` returns `int`. Always. And your file reading is wrong: you're checking for EOF _before_ `getline`!!!!

Comment: can u edit my code as what should i do then instead?

Comment: No, I'll give you more than 5 minutes to try to figure that out by yourself, first.

Comment: not happening anything my Ms Word not responding when i tried to "save as type plain.txt"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have copied down some text from pdf either from Adobe or Nitro and pasted in notepad as a .txt. Never do such thing always try to either by write your self or use Notepad editor. I also faced such thing while doing compiler. My teacher gave me inputs in pdf file and i copied. Sorry for late reply i was reading Light comments and me a laugh that he such you.... Good Luck!

Comment: aah finally done thanks buddy you save my time. The Lightness who was becoming smart to teach me just sucked me. Thanks i wish i could give 5 stars....

Answer (score 2):

Your `input.txt` is encoded in Unicode, but your console is not set to render Unicode.

Save your file as plain ASCII.

Comment: u mean "Save As" in ASCII not ".txt"?

Comment: there is option Encoding type and it is ANSI is it that u are saying?

Comment: Console? I guess it has nothing to do with the fact he is reading char instead of wchar?

Comment: @Rado: Nothing at all. This program is just a byte-wise pass-through.

Comment: yes console. it was working fine for me but i dont know wt happens to my compiler :(

Comment: btw notepad does not have the option it has unicode, utf and ANSI